# DBI: How to get identifier quote character early?

Tags: perl, dbi, identifier, quote

Is it possible to find out the identifier quote character for a certain driver before I have a database handle?

Comment: If it's constant for a DBD, you can build a table. So the real question is: Is it constant for every given DBD? (If it was, why did they make it a DBH method?)

Comment: @ikegami But if it is not constant for every DBD how does `DBI->data_sources($driver)` already know the right quote character?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `data_sources`, but the docs say it returns a DSN. What's that got to do with quote characters?

Comment: @ikegami Are the quotes around the database name `dbi:Pg:dbname="datäbase"` (returned by `data_sources()`) driver independent?

Comment: That's unrelated to your question .That's not SQL. That's not an SQL identifier.